# Pass state updater clickHandler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app like:

Main.js-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'underscore';

import ApplicationsButtons from '../components/ApplicationsButtons';


let applications_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8889/api/applications'


export default class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {applications: [], selected_app: 1};
      this.updateSelectedApp = this.updateSelectedApp.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: applications_url,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            let objects = data.objects;
            let apps = objects.map(function(object) {
                return {name: object.name, id: object.id};
            });
            console.log(apps);
            self.setState({applications: apps});
        }
    });
  }

  updateSelectedApp(id) {
      this.setState({selected_app: id});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.selected_app}
        <ApplicationsButtons apps={this.state.applications} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

ApplicationsButtons.js-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class ApplicationsButtons extends Component {

  render() {
    var buttons = null;
    let apps = this.props.apps;
    let clickHandler = this.props.clickHandler;
    if (apps.length > 0) {
        buttons = apps.map(function(app) {
            return (<button key={app.id}>{app.name} - {app.id}</button>);
            // return (<button onClick={clickHandler.apply(null, app.id)} key={app.id}>{app.name} - {app.id}</button>);
        });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {buttons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to pass an onClick to the buttons that will change the currently selected app. Somehow, I just got my first infinite loop in React ("setState has just ran 20000 times"). Apparently, when I tried to pass the event handler to be called on click, I told it to keep calling it.

The onClick function should change `state.selected_app` for the `Main` component, based on the `id` for the button that was clicked.

Comment: Maybe not related, but this line has side effect: `this.setState({selected_app: id});` . Should be `this.setState({...this.state, selected_app: id});` so `applications` array is not deleted.

Comment: I thought it just ignores the other parts of your state now, im using most recent react v15

Comment: @codyc4321 You're right, `setState` uses [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) under the hood so your `setState` line is fine.

Comment: In response to your question, try replacing `apply` with `bind`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the handler as prop.
Here's what you should do:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.selected_app}
      <ApplicationsButtons 
         apps={this.state.applications} 
         handleClick={this.updateSelectedApp}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in ApplicationButtons:

```
render() {
  var buttons = null;
  let apps = this.props.apps;
  let clickHandler = this.props.handleClick;
  if (apps.length > 0) {
    buttons = apps.map(app => 
      <button key={app.id} onClick={() => clickHandler(app.id)}>{app.name} - {app.id}</button>);
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {buttons}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I was, that was just my example code. But ty this works, I forgot to use the new es6 way which binds this for you

Comment: You can also do `onClick={clickHandler.bind(this, app.id)}`.